# iphone app that takes photo or video in one view

Tags: objective-c, video, photo

i am looking for some sample code/tutorial that will demonstrate taking a photo or video using one view in an iPhone app, with a toggle switch. Similar to the built-in iOS camer app.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This library includes the functionality for both photo and video taking. Also, it allows you to present a popup for the user to select photo/video.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fdtake